# UINavigationBar and constraint

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, constraints

I can not find a solution. If to the main view put child view, then When setting constraints child view located under UINavigationBar (unlike UITableViev). It is necessary a margin top 64 pixels. When you turn the iphone changing height and accordingly there is a space (see photo). How to solve the problem?[photo 1](http://s017.radikal.ru/i432/1409/e8/98f4760cc2cf.png)
[photo 2](http://s58.radikal.ru/i160/1409/93/621ea278167c.jpg)